# Can't find the "Run" menu in Android Studio Eel

Tags: android-studio

I have a question:

In Android Studio, there should be a menu "Run" (when you run the app, it shows console output) but, since the newest update this "Run" menu is gone. Where do I find it?
[image: Picture]

Here from Android Studio Help website, the "Run" menu at the bottom is visible
[image: Picture]

I tried to use the search menu (double shift) and I also searched the settings and tried to find solutions online, but e.g. this website has this menu.

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro?utm_source=android-studio

Answer (score 1):

[image: Find answer here]

Go to view -> Tool Windows and you can find Run